# Can I modify Darktable's default scale and position of watermarks?

Tags: darktable

I add an `svg` image as an watermark to my pictures edited in Darktable. This always starts with 100% scale and centered.

Can I modify (may be `darktable.css`/`darktable.rc`) so that the default scale is 30%, and positioned at the bottom right?

Answer (score 3):

To change the actual default, you would have to modify the source code (which you could certainly do, since it's an open source application)... but you can easily accomplish what you want with a *[preset](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s02s03.html.php)*.

Just get the module set up the way you want it, then select "Store new preset..." from the module's drop-down menu (the little "burger" icon in the upper left). Give it a name, maybe something like "default", and check the box for "auto apply this preset to matching images". The default criteria will match everything; you can refine the selection if you want.

Save the preset, and if you don't actually want it to be *activated* by default, you can de-activate the module, then select "update preset " from the same menu as before. Now the settings will be applied to the module every time an image is loaded, but the module won't be activated.